# How do I run a task inside nodejs, I get npm run error

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Alright, I have a extremelly newbie question to ask. How do I run the code I have on my visual estudio code?
I see my files with the code inside (the code I took it from a github public tutorial) now, in one part of the tutorial it says "let's check how it works" and types the command npm run install and then inside of the IDE terminal the code starts to run.
Now, unfortunately, the tutorial never mentions in what file we are (is it a new file) or if it's just the IDE main terminal calling up the program main function.
So, what I tried to do was to put the same line of code on the terminal of visual estudio code, and I get this error:

'npm' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Now, what I am thinking is that I need to type npm install in a specific window, but on the tutorial is just stated "let's take a look at the program"
sorry, I feel as I am asking were do I put the keys to enter my house, it is an extremelly simple/dumb question, but I guess these little details are what make newbies like me get lost in the most simple tasks.
I also tried the menu on visual studio code, click on terminal and then on run task and then select one of the options that are on the default -install or npm run start. Same error.

Comment: Is npm installed globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `npm` globally. If you are using Windows you will probably need to add it in environment variables also. Check also if you have install `Node.js` (when you install `Node.js`, `npm` will be automatically installed).

You can check this Docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm

Once you do that you can use `npm` as a command in your terminal.